# Connecting Blade OS to Internet with Cisco 3020 Switch Module

Tags: centos, redhat, hp-proliant, bridge, ilo

I am very new to server networking, and appreciate any help.

I have an HP c7000 with Proliant G8 blades. I have installed RHEL, Centos, and Windows Server on different blades, trying to get any of them to connect. I have 4 Cisco 3020 switch modules to the top 4 slots of the enclosure. I've tried connecting Ethernet from my router to each port of the switches, but none of the OSs find a network.

Do I need to map IPs or something more than simply plugging in the switch modules? I am running the OSs over iLO, which I connect to over LAN, would that conflict with the connectivity?

Thanks, and sorry if this is a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just had to reset the previously configured switch module and the network connected automatically with no problem!